# libevent based echo server got stuck

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

Here is an libevent based on echoServer with a little bit of my tweak (very minor).

The question is, when running a client simulation again, it appears to be stuck.  Here is how the client does: it open a TCP connection to this server, send a small data (about 20B) and wait for a reply, then it close the connection with TCP RST and then repeat.

After thousands (sometimes ~20000) iterations, the client stopped.
Wireshark listening on loopback interface showed that when it stopped, the last TCP session has data sent from client, but the server was not echoing/sending it back to client, causing the client to hang.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <event.h>
#include <event2/listener.h>
#include <event2/bufferevent_ssl.h>

struct event_base *base;

static void echo_read_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx) {
    /* This callback is invoked when there is data to read on bev. */
    struct evbuffer *input = bufferevent_get_input(bev);
    struct evbuffer *output = bufferevent_get_output(bev);
    
    /* Copy all the data from the input buffer to the output buffer. */
    int ret = evbuffer_add_buffer(output, input);
    if (ret) {
        printf("error happened when adding buf\n");
    }
}

static void echo_event_cb(struct bufferevent *bev, short events, void *ctx) {
    if (events & (BEV_EVENT_EOF|BEV_EVENT_ERROR)) {
        int fd = bufferevent_getfd(bev);
        evutil_closesocket(fd);
        bufferevent_free(bev);

        return;
    }
}
static void accept_error_cb(struct evconnlistener *listener, void *ctx) {
    struct event_base *base = evconnlistener_get_base(listener);
    int err = EVUTIL_SOCKET_ERROR();
    fprintf(stderr, "Got an error %d (%s) on the listener. "
            "Shutting down.\n", err, evutil_socket_error_to_string(err));
}

static void accept_conn_cb(struct evconnlistener *serv, int sock, struct sockaddr *sa,
             int sa_len, void *arg) {
    struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(
            base, sock, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);
    int flag = 1; 
    setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, (char *) &flag, sizeof(int));
    bufferevent_setcb(bev, echo_read_cb, NULL, echo_event_cb, NULL);

    bufferevent_enable(bev, EV_READ|EV_WRITE);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct evconnlistener *listener;
    struct sockaddr_in sin;

    memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(9999);
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(0x7f000001); /* 127.0.0.1 */

    base = event_base_new();
    listener = evconnlistener_new_bind(base, accept_conn_cb, NULL,
            LEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|LEV_OPT_REUSEABLE, -1,
            (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin));
    if (!listener) {
            perror("Couldn't create listener");
            return 1;
    }
    evconnlistener_set_error_cb(listener, accept_error_cb);
    event_base_loop(base, 0);

    evconnlistener_free(listener);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All ephemeral ports stuck in TIME_WAIT?

Comment: All the completed sessions ended with client sending TCP RESET.  For the stuck session, according to wireshark,  After TCP handshake is complete, client sent the data to server, but server didn't send data back to client (supposed to echo). 
Added some instrument on the `echo_read_cb`, turned out the server side thinks the client data didn't come for the stuck session.  I am confused. Maybe something internal to libevent is preventing the firing of the call back function `echo_read_cb`. ???

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the cause of the problem: in the function `echo_event_cb`, there is a call `evutil_closesocket(fd)`; This is not only unnecessary, it's harmful! After the call to close socket is removed, it works perfect.

It's unnecessary because the bufferedevent was created with `BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE`.